# How to force points above maximum to be on maximum grid line, but still show real value in tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I'm drawing a really simple line chart with hours slept each day. So hours are on the y axis and dates on the x axis. The y axis goes from 0 to 23, but interesting values are usually between 3 and 12, so I only want to draw these values. This is easy, just define min and max on yaxis.

But now highcharts will still draw values above and below the min and max y valus. What I want is to have it just draw values above 12 on the 12 max grid line, and show the real value in the tooltip, and the inverse for values below 3.

Illustration of problem: https://jsfiddle.net/HhP39/10/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {},
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Hours'
          },
        min: 3,
        max: 12,
        tickInterval: 1
      },
        series: [{
            data: [2,6,13,4,9,12,6,8,1,15,9,7,5,8,14,5,8,2,3]
        }]
    });
});
```

As you can see, values just out of range, such as 2, will still produce a tooltip if you hover over where they are. I want all values like these to move to be on the min and max lines.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this update to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HhP39/7/

It's creating an array of the original values and then an array of the adjusted values.  The graph actually charts the adjusted values but the tooltip pulls from the original values.

```
data = [2,6,13,4,9,12,6,8,1,15,9,7,5,8,14,5,8,2,3];
series = [];
tooltips = [];
for (var i in data) {
    tooltips.push(data[i]);
    series.push( Math.max(3, Math.min(data[i], 12)) );
}
```

And then chart it with:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {},
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Hours'
      },
    min: 3,
    max: 12,
    tickInterval: 1
  },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return ('Real value: ' + data[this.x]);
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: series
    }]
});
```

Comment: Great Thanks!

One note, this fiddle stopped working because the link to highcharts.js wasn't https. Updated the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/HhP39/9/